# Find registry key by value and delete it

Tags: powershell, registry

I want to search for a registry key and delete that key. I know the value of the key and the path, but not the name.

```
Open     REG_SZ    /R "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\Analysis\ANALYS32.XLL"
Open1   REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\SOLVER\SOLVER.XLAM"
Open2   REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\EUROTOOL.XLAM"
```

So the value is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\EUROTOOL.XLAM"` and on this host the name is `Open2` but the name can change from host to host.

I tried it with `Get-Item`, but unfortunately I didn't get anywhere with that.

Comment: You might read the registry key with ```get-childitem``` and properties with ```get-itemproperty```. If you want to enable/disable Addins in Office I'd better go [that](https://daniel.streefkerkonline.com/2014/04/09/re-enable-microsoft-office-add-ins-with-powershell/) way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the exact key with the property values , then you can find the name by using this snippet:

```
$keypath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\folder\"

$properties = Get-ItemProperty $keypath
 foreach ($property in $properties.psobject.properties) {

 if($property.value -eq "value that you want to match with"){
  "Removing property $property"
  Remove-ItemProperty -Name $property.name -Path $keypath 
 }
 }
```